# Image rotation moving resulting image unpredictably

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, gdi, system.drawing

I've been looking all over SO today and I can't get anything to work for my needs.

I have a web application that let's users drag and drop text/images and then it sends the details to the server to draw those to a pdf.  I'm trying to enable rotation, but I can't get a hold of the translatetransform stuff.  My image in testing prints out great, rotated well, but it is not in the correct location.  I'm missing how the intitial translatetransform changes things and my mind is shot at the end of the day.  Do I have to draw this as a bitmap first using a different graphics instance, and then draw that bitmap to my background?  Any help on this would be great!  Thanks!

CODE:

- i is the image object from the browser
- coord is the x & y of the upper corner of the image on the canvas (990wx1100h) on the browser
- size is the h & w of the element on the browser

  ```
                          Bitmap b = new Bitmap(wc.OpenRead(i.img));
                          if (i.rotation != 0)
                          {
                              g.TranslateTransform(this.CanvasDetails.size.width/2, this.CanvasDetails.size.height/2);
                              g.RotateTransform(i.rotation);
                              g.DrawImage(b, new Rectangle(- i.coord.x/2, -i.coord.y/2, i.size.width, i.size.height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              g.DrawImage(b, new Rectangle(i.coord.x, i.coord.y, i.size.width, i.size.height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
                          }
  ```

  **EDIT**
  I added the translatransform reversal as suggested by Adam, but the image is still drawn in a different location.

  ```
                                  g.TranslateTransform(this.CanvasDetails.size.width / 2, this.CanvasDetails.size.height / 2);
                              g.RotateTransform(i.rotation);
                              g.TranslateTransform(-this.CanvasDetails.size.width / 2, -this.CanvasDetails.size.height / 2);
                              g.DrawImage(b, new Rectangle(-i.coord.x / 2, -i.coord.y / 2, i.size.width, i.size.height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
  ```

Examples:
Browser View
[image: Browser View]

.NET drawn version
[image: Server Side Product]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, completely reworking this answer to try to explain it clearer. A couple of things to know are that transformations 'accumulate' and rotation transforms happen around the origin. So to just explain the affect of accumulating (multiplying) transforms, look at this example:

```
            //draw an ellipse centered at 200,200
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 195, 195, 10, 10);

            //apply translate transform - shifts origin to 200,200
            g.TranslateTransform(200, 200);

            //draw another ellipse, should draw around first ellipse
            //because translate tranforms essentially moves our coordinates 200,200
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, -7, -7, 14, 14);

            //now do rotate transform
            g.RotateTransform(90f); //degree to rotate object

            //now, anything we draw with coordinates 0,0 is actually going to be draw at 200,200 AND be rotated by 45*
            //this line will be vertical, through 200,200, instead of horizontal through 0,0
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Green, -20,0,20,0);

            //If we add another translate, this time 50x, it would normally translate by 50 in the X direction
            //BUT - because we already have transforms applied, including the 90 rotate, it affects this translation
            //so this in effect because a 50px translation in Y, because it's rotated 90*
            g.TranslateTransform(50, 0);

            //so even though we translated 50x, this line will draw 50px below the last line
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Green, -20, 0, 20, 0);
```

So for your case, you want to draw an object Centered at CenterPoint and rotated by Angle. So you would do:

```
g.TranslateTransform(-CenterPoint.X, -CenterPoint.Y);
g.RotateTransform(Angle);
g.DrawImage(b, -ImageSize/2, -ImageSize/2, ImageSize, ImageSize);
```

You'd then need to reset the transforms for additional drawing, which you can do with:

```
g.ResetTransform();
```

If that doesn't leave the image where you want it, then you'll need to check the values you're using to position it. Are you storing it's center? Or top left? Etc.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.  'CanvasDetails' is the background that I'm drawing the image onto.  I'm really confused here.  Should I be using the drawimage with the rectangle, or not?  I have no clue how to get this to jive.

Comment: Could you put a little more of your code and a better example of what is different with between your web and .net side? This is likely an issue with multiple transforms, but without more code it's hard to see exactly what

Comment: Thanks for the details, I'll try that now and see what I can get to work.  I really appreciate the extra insight!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much man.  Your explanation really helped and I just got it to work.  You really helped me out and I very much appreciate it.  If you are ever in NYC, send me a message and I'll buy you a beer!  Thanks again!

Comment: no worries. I would recommend looking into using matrices to to store your translations/transformations/rotations etc from the web app to your other app though, it's much cleaner and less prone to issues.

Comment: I'll check it out.  Luckily the only thing the web app utilizes is rotation, they can't to any other transformations... yet.  Thanks again.